# Eclipse not updates when I make change in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, ellipse, eclipse-oxygen

I am running a `jsf` project. I using `sublimetext 3` for working with `html` and `css`. whenever I make changes and refresh the browser the browser not updated the corrections what I made unless I refresh manually in `eclipse` or waiting a `minutes`.

But this is not going to help me for my `html` development. any one help me to sort this out?

here is my config file in eclipse:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200
```

[image]

Comment: Why down votes..? What is wrong with me?

Comment: These downvotes don't look right, especially as some other questions are getting similar treatment (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366298/2670892)). Raised moderator flag.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `jsf`; are you saying that there is some sort of web server running in Eclipse, but Eclipse doesn't notice automatically when you edit files in Sublime? Does the same thing happen if you use something like `notepad` to do the same thing?

Comment: Yes you are correct. But I don't try with notepad